# Hibernate + c3p0 + postgres = SQLState: 08006 An I/O error occured while sending to the backend

Tags: hibernate, timeout

Hi i have an Transactional annotated service function which makes a call to an external rest Api which sometimes fast and somtimes takes about 10 secs.

When the api returns fast everything works, when it takes too long hibernate gives me this exception:

```
http-bio-8080-exec-5 03/06/2014 16:05:59,346 | WARN | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | logExceptions | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
http-bio-8080-exec-5 03/06/2014 16:05:59,351 | ERROR | org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | logExceptions | An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
http-bio-8080-exec-5 03/06/2014 16:05:59,353 | WARN | com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection | handleThrowable | [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
http-bio-8080-exec-5 03/06/2014 16:05:59,354 | WARN | com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection | handleThrowable | [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:714)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.rollback(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:731)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:209)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:574)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:493)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:264)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
```

the postgres server logs this

```
2014-06-03 16:04:40 CEST LOG:  unvollstÃ¤ndige Message vom Client
```

unvollstÃ¤ndige Message vom Client ~~ incomplete message from client

so i assume there is any timeout... but i dont know where, my hibernate config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Connection properties -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname" />
    <property name="user" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />
    <!-- Pool properties -->
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="10" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300000" />
    <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false
            hibernate.max_fetch_depth=0
        </value>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem was this line

```
Restrictions.in("id", hugeidlist)
```

hugeidlist came from the external api and contained over 100.000 entries, which generated a too long query, i've splitted the list now